# Input impedance circuit

Tags: capacitor, frequency, impedance, kirchhoffs-laws, input-impedance

Please can you assist me in my solution if it correct. I need to know the basics if a negative resistor will change my node two equation? are my natural frequencies correct? Please help. Thanks.[image: Question]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider definition of input impedance of a circuit:

> The input impedance of an electrical network is the impedance from the source into the network being connected. In other words, the input impedance is the impedance, if placed across the input terminals, that would produce the same voltage across and current through the input terminals as the electrical network being connected.

In simple words, If you place a voltage source of Vin volts across the input terminals, and the current that flows through it is Iin, then

[image]

Similarly, here Vin=V1

[image]

Thus, [image]

or [image]

Pole of Zin= -1/2